# Spring 3 DataSourceTransactionManager sporadically timing out when getting transaction to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In a nutshell, when I try and get a connection after not having used a transaction for several minutes the first transaction setup  fails.

When things are working, my logs show the following for a simple transaction:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'getRecord' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_30; ''
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.example.services.Service.getRecord]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_30; ''
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [jdbc:mysql://dev-db.example.com:3306/example, UserName=foo@1.2.3.4, MySQL Connector Java] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://dev-db.example.com:3306/example, UserName=foo@1.2.3.4, MySQL Connector Java] to manual commit
```

However, if I haven't had any activity for several minutes, instead I will get this message:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'getRecord' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_30; ''
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.example.services.Service.getRecord]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,timeout_30; ''
```

My observations so far:

- seems to be based on inactivity, but I've seen this behavior immediately after restarting my Tomcat although nothing else was hitting the database so I think it's inactivity against a network element such as my MySQL server.
- when my application starts up, it makes a few non-transactional requests from the database which have not had any problems, so it seems related to transactions.
- the timeout element in the @Transactional notation is not effective in this case. It seems to eventually time out, but takes 15 minutes (!).
- while this transaction request is busy timing out, I can make subsequent requests successfully.
- doesn't seem to be a starved local connection pool. I have seen this right after restarting the Tomcat.

When it finally times out (did I mention 15 minutes!) I get the following:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@3269c671] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [connection is closed] to manual commit
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Could not close JDBC Connection
ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
ERROR: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,312,604 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 924,748 milliseconds ago.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
```

Running Spring 3.1.1, mysql 5.1.32, commons-dbcp 1.4 and commons-pool 1.5.4.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: put your ApplicationContext.xml here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that MySQL server timeouts idle JDBC connections. This has nothing to do with the TransactionManager set-up.

Have a look at your DataSource set-up. It shall tests connection on connection retrieval and/or validate idle connections in pool.

In commons-dbcp you can set-up test on connection retrieval via the testOnBorrow and validationQuery properties.

Comment: I was thinking that too, except that when my app starts up it makes three quick requests which **never** timeout, but the first _transaction_ fails. Unless transactions are using a separate connection type which has a different idle time timeout, I can't conclude it's a connection-wide problem.

Comment: Requests done at application start do not time-out as at the start time the connection pool just gets created. Depending on the set-up

Comment: ...continued...depending on the set-up of the DataSource they even might get newly created virgin connection.

Comment: There is a time-out value for the transaction, these are the 30 seconds
visible in your log, and yes this value gets propagated into the 
MySQl Jdbc Connection. However, IMHO this value is used to limit the duration 
of one transaction, not the time between the transactions on one connection.
This value might be configured on transaction level, e.g. on the @Transactional.
You might try to set it to 0, which means 'never' for MySQL. 
Nevertheless, IMHO the correct solution is to set-up the testOnBorrow 
property of the data source.